# How To implement ReactFlagsSelect with React Hook Form Controller

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I tried to implement  with React Hook From using `<Controller />`. While I am submitting the form country field return `undefined`.

```js
<Controller 
  name="country"
  control={control}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
    <ReactFlagsSelect
      selected={selected}
      onSelect={code => handleChange(code)}
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you pass RHF's `onChange` handler to the wrong prop. `<ReactFlagsSelect />` doesn't have a `onChange` prop, instead you should pass it to the `onSelect` prop.

```js
<Controller 
  name="country"
  control={control}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
    <ReactFlagsSelect
      selected={selected}
      onSelect={onChange}
      value={value}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Side-note: RHF's will update value changes to your registered fields in it's internal form state, so there is no need to use extra state management for these values via `useState` or something similar. If you really need to call your `handleChange` callback, you can do both in the `onSelect` callback.

```js
<Controller 
  name="country"
  control={control}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
    <ReactFlagsSelect
      selected={selected}
      onSelect={code => {
        onChange(code);
        handleChange(code);
      }}
      value={value}
    />
  )}
/>
```